# Symfony2 Doctrine, joining tables by its foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've imported two tables with data that were given to me into the Symfony database and want to join the two by a foreign key.

Table **Main** has columns: ID, indate, dano, partno, batchno
Table **Sub** has columns: ID, main_id, rackno, code, qty

I want to join the tables together as a one to many(?) since one main can have many subs. For example, one dano can have many rackno. I am guessing the *main_id* in Table **Sub** and *id* in Table **Main** are the keys that will be used to join.

How do I go about joining the two with Doctrine? I have the tables separated by its own Entity files.

On Main.php

```
class Main
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sub", mappedBy="mainId")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $indate;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $dano;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $partno;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $batchno;
```

On Sub.php:

```
class Sub
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $mainId;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $rackno;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $qty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't process like this. If you need an ManyToOne relation, you need this:

In your Main class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sub", mappedBy="main")
 */
private $sub;
```

And in your Sub class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main", inversedBy="sub")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $main;
```

And don't forget to sync your database ;)

Comment: But I wanted to match the data in main_id from Sub table to the id in the Main table. Creating the $sub and $main will just create another column with empty data?

Comment: In your Sub table (Entity Sub), your will have a main_id field will be stored the id of this.

Main can have many Sub

BUT

Sub can't have many Main

Comment: @Nept is correct. I suggest you read more about association mappings here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html.